# Audio Files downloaded from DownloadManager does not reflecting in MediaStore on Android Q

Tags: android, mediastore, android-10.0

i am using DownloadManager to download an audio file

```
    val token = getAccessToken()
    val request = DownloadManager.Request(uri)
        .addRequestHeader("Authorization", "OAuth $token")
        .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC, fileName)
        .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner()
    val downloadManager = context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
    downloadManager.enqueue(request)
```

but downloaded file does not reflect in MediaStore. I know that allowScanningByMediaScanner() is deprecated in android 10. are there any alternatives?

Comment: Are they really in the Music directory?

Comment: Reboot your device and they will.

Comment: I have the same problem. No solution found?